# How to dynamically dump dex using frida in Android 12

Tags: android, dex, frida

I am currently trying to dynamically dump dex using frida in Android 12.

In Android 9 version, the well-known **frida-dexdump** tool was used.

Or, with the frida code below, dex was dumped successfully in Android 9 version.

In android 9, dex was dumped by hooking the `_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE` function in **libart.so.**

Isn't hooking **libart.so** to dump dex in Android 12?

**In Android 12**, the correct dex could not be dumped using the **frida-dexdump tool** above.

Is there a way to dynamically dump dex using frida in **Android 12** version?

Or is there any good tool or frida code?

Comment: Have you tried to load `libart.so` of Android 12 (if it exists) into Ghidra or IDA Pro and check if there is still a `art::ClassLinker::DefineClass(..)` method or something similar? The paper [PackerGrind: An Adaptive Unpacking
System for Android Apps](https://cslxue.github.io/papers/packergrind-tse.pdf) is from 2022 (hopefully it covers Android 12) and contains some starting points, especially table1 my be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I built a custom OS based on AOSP. The Android version is version 12, and I checked whether the libart.so file you mentioned is present. (/system/lib, /system/lib64)
But there was no libart.so file anywhere.